# Animate transition between column and row while scrolling in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, animation, android-jetpack-compose, android-transitions

When I scroll in a list, I want the composable sticky header to shrink. During that shrinking, the layout should by animated by the scrolling state to switch from a column layout, to a row layout.

Is there any way to achieve this in Jetpack Compose?

It should look like this:
[image]

Comment: Does anybody know how to achieve this? I still haven't figured it out on how to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try use `MotionLayout` – it's like Constraint Layout but much better:

```
implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:1.0.1"
```

Firstly create a motion scene in json5 format. For your situation it will be something like this:

```
{
  ConstraintSets: {
    start: {
      value: {
        start: [ 'parent', 'start' ],
        top: [ 'parent', 'top' ],
      },
      title: {
        start: [ 'parent', 'start' ],
        top: [ 'value', 'bottom' ],
      }
    },
    end: {
      value: {
        top: [ 'parent', 'top' ],
        start: [ 'title', 'end' ],
      },
      title: {
        start: [ 'parent', 'start' ],
        top: [ 'parent', 'top' ],
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`MotionLayout` gets 3 required parameters: motionScene (string with json5 above), content (your composable) and progress value (float from 0 to 1).

1. Create scroll state and progress calculation:

   val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
   val progress = (scrollState.value.toFloat() / 100).takeIf { it <= 1 } ?: 1f
2. Create `MotionLayout`:

   ```
    MotionLayout(
        motionScene = MotionScene(<json5 string>),
        progress = progress
    ) {
        Text(modifier = Modifier.layoutId("value"), text = "Value")
        Text(modifier = Modifier.layoutId("title"), text = "Title")
    }
   ```
3. Connect the `scrollState` to your scrollable content:

   ```
    Column(modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(scrollState)) {
        repeat(20) {
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(16.dp),
                text = it.toString()
            )
        }
    }
   ```

[the result of scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hv5Mr.gif)

Comment: https://twitter.com/RodrigoMartinD/status/1577719043720626178?s=20&t=5w19yA6WVrPaXI4-fIs-PA

This looks close to what you are looking for and he has a repo with github.